# Custom drop down in ckeditor v4

Tags: ckeditor

Does anyone have a sample/plugin that shows a custom drop down list and simply inserts some text into the wysiwyg editor? I have searched the internet and the plugins but can't find out how to do this for ckeditor v4. There are plenty of samples for v3.

Basically I have the following that I want to add as a dropdown list on the editor toolbar

```
<option value="{{firstname}}">Firstname</option>
<option value="{{lastname}}">Lastname</option>
<option value="{{company}}">Company</option>
```

**edit** as an afterthought I went back to the plugins and found this [placeholder](http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder) plugin. This actually might suit me better, I will have a go at replacing the textbox with a select list.

However it would still be nice to add a custom dropdown list to the toolbar...

Comment: Whatever code you found for v3 should work with v4. I don't think that the API has changed anything about that part.